# Anyone works with AusPost API? My shipments are missing

Tags: api, integration

I wrote a custom system that integrates AusPost API for creating shipments/labels and for dispatching goods.
System was tested against AusPost testbed and I am now allowed to use production envrionment.
When switched to production environment, I am able to create shipments, however they do not appear when I log into my eParcel account. I can only retrieve the shipment using API.

Location ID is same and so are product codes. I checked my eParcel account details against GetAccountDetails API response.

The question is -- if someone else integrated AusPost eParcel API, can they tell me if you suppose to see shipments created via API when you log into your eParcel account? Or, perhaps, someone know what can be wrong.

Yes, I did ask AusPost. They do not have phone number and e-mail support is not very responsive. So, hopefully, someone can enlighten me here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone is interested, answer is "yeas" and "no".

No, you will not see your orders in eParcel web interface.

But you can see them through MyPost Business account! Somehow two are linked and you just have to make sure you selected same location code as your eParcel system. Why it is like that? No idea. Australia Post works in mysterious ways. One of their techs alerted me to this mechanism.

Also, you can always just use API to get the list of all outstanding packages and do whatever you have to do on your side.